# How to declare member template of class template as friend?

Tags: c++, templates

Given the following code:

```cpp
template <typename T, typename D> class B;

template <typename T>
class A {
public:
  A() { }
  template <typename D>
  A(B<T, D>);
};

template <typename T, typename D>
class B {
  friend A<T>::A(B<T, D>);
  int x;
};

template <typename T>
template <typename D>
A<T>::A(B<T, D> b) {
  b.x = 42;
}

int main() {
  B<int, double> b;
  A<int> a(b);
  return 0;
}
```

I want to declare member template `A(B<T, D>)` of class template `A<T>` as friend.

So I declared, `friend A<T>::A(B<T, D>);`

But I got a compile error:

```
test.cc: In instantiation of ‘class B<int, double>’:
test.cc:24:18:   required from here
test.cc:13:10: error: prototype for ‘A<int>::A(B<int, double>)’ does not match any in class ‘A<int>’
   friend A<T>::A(B<T, D>);
          ^~~~
test.cc:4:7: error: candidates are: constexpr A<int>::A(A<int>&&)
 class A {
       ^
test.cc:4:7: error:                 constexpr A<int>::A(const A<int>&)
test.cc:8:3: error:                 template<class D> A<T>::A(B<T, D>) [with D = D; T = int]
   A(B<T, D>);
   ^
test.cc:6:3: error:                 A<T>::A() [with T = int]
   A() { }
   ^
test.cc: In instantiation of ‘A<T>::A(B<T, D>) [with D = double; T = int]’:
test.cc:25:13:   required from here
test.cc:20:5: error: ‘int B<int, double>::x’ is private within this context
   b.x = 42;
   ~~^
test.cc:14:7: note: declared private here
   int x;
       ^
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Why not make the whole `A<T>` class a friend?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Of course that's the right way too. But I wonder if this is possible.

Comment: Do you want the _member template_ to be a friend or just the specific specialization with the classes' template parameters?

Comment: You can define a `class A` as `friend` of `B`. [DEMO](https://onlinegdb.com/RPNma9pA2)

Comment: @user17732522 I want the member template to be a friend.

Comment: @TruthSeeker Of course that's the right way too. But I wonder if this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important part of the error message seems to be this line:

```
test.cc:8:3: error:                 template<class D> A<T>::A(B<T, D>) [with D = D; T = int]
```

Notice how the template type `D` is *not* expanded to the actual type.

That lead me to believe that adding a new template type for the `friend` declaration might help:

```
template<typename U>
friend A<T>::A(B<T, U>);
```

And it [works in my testing](https://godbolt.org/z/8Wcjhsxa7).

---

After thinking a little bit about the reasons behind this, I think it's because there's really no such (constructor) function as `A::A(B<T, D>)`, only the *template* `template<typename D> A::A(B<T, D>)`.

Comment: Thanks. However, that enables the following code: `A<T>::A(B<T, D>) { B<T, T> b; b.x = 42; }` (of course that's stupid) Is there any way to limit it more strongly?

Comment: @bessapple14 That is what I asked you under the question. Whether you want the template itself to be friended or only the specific specialization. This answer assumes that you want to friend the template as such as you are asking in the question.